# Java mouseClicked shows JFrame between 5 ~ 10 times instead of 1

Tags: java, jframe, mouselistener

I'm trying to code a game for school, for which I have to use a MouseListener. I am using the MouseListener for the main menu. I want the option "Spelregels" (which translates into rules) to create and show a new JFrame containing the rules for the game.

```
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MouseInput implements MouseListener {

    Main mainMenu = new Main();

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();

//      public Rectangle startNieuwSpelButton = new Rectangle(100, 275, 250, 50);
//      public Rectangle hervatSpelButton = new Rectangle(100, 340, 250, 50);
//      public Rectangle spelregelsButton = new Rectangle(100, 405, 250, 50);
//      public Rectangle highscoresButton = new Rectangle(100, 470, 250, 50);

        // Start Nieuw Spel Button
        if(mx >= 100 && mx <= 350) {
            if (my >= 275 && my <= 325) {
                System.out.println("Je hebt op de startNieuwSpelButton geklikt.");
            }
        }

        // Hervat Spel Button
        if(mx >= 100 && mx <= 350) {
            if (my >= 340 && my <= 390) {
                System.out.println("Je hebt op de hervatSpelButton geklikt.");
            }
        }

        // Spelregels Button
        if(mx >= 100 && mx <= 350) {
            if (my >= 405 && my <= 455) {
                JFrame spelregelFrame = new JFrame("Lunar Lockout Spelregels");
                spelregelFrame.setSize(450, 650);
                spelregelFrame.setLocation(800, 100);
                spelregelFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        }

        // Highscore Button
        if(mx >= 100 && mx <= 350) {
            if (my >= 470 && my <= 520) {
                System.out.println("Je hebt op de highscoreButton geklikt.");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

That's the code that I'm using. I was wondering why it's showing the JFrame multiple times. Like so: http://puu.sh/7UuJb.jpg .

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Comment: you're creating multiple `JFrames` inside your `MouseListener`...

Comment: Can you show the code where you install your mouse listener?  It sounds to me like you may be installing multiple copies of the listener.

Comment: @Herms I added MouseListener to paintComponent which contains the following code: http://pastebin.com/mCdAd8Jy and I'm sorry but could you elaborate as to why I'm creating multiple JFrames? As far as I can see I am only creating one called spelregelFrame but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @user3494467 I think that's your problem. I believe paintComponent will be called every time the component needs to be updated.  Each time it's painted you're adding another mouse listener, so the more times it's painted the more times that happens.

Comment: @Herms Have you got any suggestions how I can make it so that it only paints once? And thank you for responding so quickly.

Comment: You don't want it painting only once. It will need to repaint occasionally as the screen redraws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding your mouse listener in `paintComponent`, which is called any time the component needs to be repainted, you should add it in the constructor.  That way your panel will only have one mouse listener.

As it stands you add a new one every time you repaint, so they'll keep building up.

So, basically:

```
public class HoofdMenu extends JPanel {
  // ... member vars

  public HoofdMenu() {
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // ... don't add listener in here
  }
```

Comment: I've got one more question if you don't mind me asking. Is it possible to set the original frame of the main menu to false so that it doesn't show the main menu no more? I tried to add frame.setVisible(false); (which is the main menu) to the MouseListener however that gave me an error. Because it doesn't know that variable.

Comment: Not sure. It's been a long time since I've dealt with Java UIs so I'm not sure.  Might be worth asking as a new question though.  Someone else might know.